# Using variable in Pgsql Select query is giving issues

Tags: postgresql

I have a pgsql query as:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cast(attribute - > 'location' AS character varying) AS location
FROM table_name
WHERE attribute - > 'abc' = COALESCE('xyz', attribute - > 'abc')
AND cast(attribute - > 'location' AS character varying) NOT IN ('123')
```

It is giving proper output with all the values except for **123**

But now if I use a variable as:

**val := '('123')';**

and substitute the variable in the query as:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cast(attribute - > 'location' AS character varying) AS location
FROM table_name
WHERE attribute - > 'abc' = COALESCE('xyz', attribute - > 'abc')
AND cast(attribute - > 'location' AS character varying) NOT IN (val)
```

The value of **val** is coming as null while in the query but if I hardcode the values instead of **val**, I get desired result.

How can I use values of the variable **val** in the query? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: You would just want `val := '123'`.  Right?  It's just a string variable.  The parentheses are part of the `NOT IN` clause,  They can't be substituted.

Comment: You can't use variables with plain SQL, only inside a function (or procedure) when using PL/pgSQL. Please [edit] your question and show us your complete PL/pgSQL code.

Comment: I am trying something like this:
val := '10.0.81.45:9979','10.0.66.77:9979','10.0.49.24:9979'

This value is not getting replaced in the query but when I hardcode the same value instead of val, the query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works when hard coded but not as a parameter because the the exact code is intercepted as totally different things. When you hard code values as `in('A','B')` the interpreter sees each as an independent values separated by a comma, when you pass it as a variable as `in(val)` the interpreter sees a single variable, the commas are not separators but just part of the data value. When passed as a single variable you must parse it into the separate components. Try:

```
select distinct cast(attribute - > 'location' as character varying) as location
  from table_name
 where attribute - > 'abc' = coalesce('xyz', attribute - > 'abc')
   and cast(attribute - > 'location' as character varying) not in 
       ( select unnest(string_to_array(val)) ) ;
```

**Note:** The `coalesce` does nothing in this statement. Coalesce always returns the first non-null value. Since the literal 'xyz' is never null this will always return 'xyz'. I hope this is just an example and is actually a column or another parameter.